# raw strings in Python3, regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am getting started learning Python3 and currently I am totally lost in 'regular expressions'. In order to understand raw strings I wrote this code:

```
import re
pattern='\\n'
c='qwerty\. i am hungry. \n z'
d=r'qwerty\. i am hungry. \n z '
print(c)
print(d+'\n\n\n')
for a in (c,d,):
    if re.search(pattern,a):
        print('"{0}" contains "{1}" \n'.format(a, pattern))
    else:
        print('"{0}" does not contain "{1}" \n'.format(a, pattern))
```

Output is: first string contains pattern and the second doesn't. However, once I introduce a minor change in the pattern:

```
import re
pattern=r'\\n'
c='qwerty\. i am hungry. \n z'
d=r'qwerty\. i am hungry. \n z '
print(c)
print(d+'\n\n\n')
for a in (c,d,):
    if re.search(pattern,a):
        print('"{0}" contains "{1}" \n'.format(a, pattern))
    else:
        print('"{0}" does not contain "{1}" \n'.format(a, pattern))
```

The result gets reversed. The second string contains `r'\\n'` , which I cannot understand, since there is no double backslash in it...
Could you please explain this mystery to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the rules of interpolation:

`'\n'` becomes the ascii byte 0x0A; this applies to your first string to match.
`r'\n'` becomes the literal `\n`, that is `\` followed by `n`; this applies to the second string to match.

`'\\n'` becomes the literal `\n`; this applies to your first pattern string.
`r'\\n'` becomes the literal `\\n`; this applies to the second pattern string.

When you perform the matching there is **another round of interpolation** done on patterns by `re.search`:
the literal `\n` turns into the ascii byte 0x0A  (first pattern)
the literal `\\n` turns into the literal `\n` (second pattern)

So in the end your first string matches the first pattern as both contain ascii 0x0A,
and the second string matches the second pattern as both contain literal `\n`.

That's it, no mystery here.

Answer (score 1):

A raw string essentially tells the system to read the backslashes in the following string as what they are - backslashes. So,

```
print(r'hi\nhi')
```

Prints out `hi\nhi`.
However, the system treats backslashes in non-raw strings as a method to escape out the following character. Hence,

```
print('hi\nhi')
```

Prints:

```
hi
hi
```

So, the `\n` in non-raw strings becomes a newline.

---

In your code, `pattern` contains a string with a newline, **not a backslash and n**. Were you to use `pattern = r'\n'`, `pattern` would contain a backslash and n, **but not a newline**

Hence, searching for a `\\n` in the string, essentially tells the system to escape out a `\` (thus, it searches for a backslash) followed by `n`. 
First of all, let's clarify: `c` contains a newline, and `d` contains `\n`, literally. This can be verified by printing the strings.

- When you search for `'\\n'`, the regex pattern searches for a newline. So, `c` matches, but `d` does not match.
- When `pattern = '\n'` then `c` matches, but `d` does not.
- When `pattern = r'\\n'`, then `d` matches, but `c` does not.